Guide to the Hebrew Cantillation Marks, what patterns are allowed, and how they are organized?
I am doing work on a Hebrew dictionary (amongst other language dictionaries), and I spent quite a bit of time working on a Hebrew transliterator to help in natural language processing (beside the point). In doing so, I ran into the ~30 or so Hebrew cantillation marks, and wanted to learn a little about them, how they work, how the writer knows where to put the marks, how the notes and rhythms get defined/allowed, and generally the theory behind how to interpret them.
The best and pretty much only example I could find on the web was this quick video, leading to learntrope.com, which at least provides a somewhat simple introduction immersion. But it doesn't still explain how they work. This video was as close as I've gotten to really understanding how to apply the principles.
The site https://mechon-mamre.org/c/hr/ has some info about Kings, Dukes, Counts, etc., and disjunctions and conjuctions, and Wikipedia has a bunch of stuff somewhat explaining their history and how they work at a very high level (not a practical level).
Wikipedia groups them, like into this 2nd-level group, and it shows the possible variations of what can occur:

The following variations of the Etnachta group can occur:

Mercha, Tipcha, Munach, Etnachta
Mercha, Tipcha, Etnachta
Tipcha, Munach, Etnachta
Tipcha, Etnachta
Munach, Etnachta
Etnachta


But why are just those variations allowed and not others? I don't follow. And how do they know "these are the variations"?
Then it shows a quick image, which I have no idea (1) how to read, or (2) how it got created (who decided on this progression of notes?):

So some questions as a beginner:

What is a good way online to learn about how this works? I purchased a book on Amazon (one of the less-expensive books), and there seem to be some good $70+ books which is a little pricey. Oh also this 270 page research paper THE SYNTAX OF MASORETIC ACCENTS IN THE HEBREW BIBLE is pretty good, but it also doesn't go into how it works in practice as far as I could tell.
Do any new Hebrew documents outside the 2 main books that originated the cantillation marks, get written? If so, how do the authors decide where to put the cantillation marks?
Is it possible to learn without the melody/singing/chanting aspect of it, and at first just focus on the pausing and rhythms? If so, what is a recommended technique? If not, why not?

Basically, I would like to learn how this works in more detail, but didn't find anything good online to really dig into, beyond the few resources I linked.

Regarding 2: Essentially no. You can find some small works done with cantillation, but hobbyists gonna hobby. I've seen the Christian New Testament in Hebrew with cantillation, too.

Consider buying or borrowing this book: https://jps.org/books/chanting-the-hebrew-bible-2/

Regarding 3: Yes, it's possible. Indeed, the singing part varies pretty widely across the world, yet the way the cantillation breaks up the words is the same across the board.

Regarding 1: you might read Wickes, which is old and has some errors, but is a great free starting point that is available on the Internet Archive.

If you can read Hebrew then a classic place to start to gain understanding in the rules is R. Mordechai Breuer's "Sefer Taamei HaMikra".  It used to be out-of-print but it seems like it's now for sale here https://www.chorev.co.il/טעמי-המקרא.htm for about $28 (you would have to figure out how much international shipping would cost). a very worthwhile book.

I recommend getting the book Chanting the Hebrew Bible by Joshua Jacobson.  It's very full of information about the narrative trope.  It's not online, so you'll have to pay money for it, but it's very much worth it.  I also recommend learning the melodies (doesn't matter which tradition) so that you can get a better understanding for how the trope works as you learn their syntax.
That book does not, unfortunately, explain the Emet trope, which is the system used in the poetic books (Iyov, Mishlei, T'hilim, to spell out Emet).  That one is very interesting if you can find the resources.
